# Incorrect effect of content-editable attribute on the div content render

Tags: html, css, dom, contenteditable

Why adding `contenteditable="true"` to a span inside a div, cause break line?

```css
div{
  width: 110px;
  height: 80px;
  border:1px solid #5aa; 
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>IamANowSpaceLineSample</span>
</div>

<br/>

<div>
  <span contenteditable="true">IamANowSpaceLineSample</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text "IamANowSpaceLineSample" is longer than the 110px width you have allocated to your div. It has no spaces and no css rule saying that it can break the word to fit, so it isn't getting wrapped to fit inside its parent div, and its extending outside the div.

However when you add `contenteditable="true"` the styling changes and the following gets applied (as you can see if you check the element in the element inspector):

```
span[Attributes Style] {
    -webkit-user-modify: read-write;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    -webkit-line-break: after-white-space;
}
```

This sets `word-wrap: break-word;` which forces the browser to wrap the text to fit inside the 110px width of the parent div.

If you want to prevent it wrapping, you can use `white-space: nowrap;` (or make the div wide enough to fit!)

**Examples:**

```css
div{
  width: 110px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #aaa; 

  margin-bottom:2em;
}

span.nowrap{
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>IamANowSpaceLineSample</span>
</div>

<div>
  <span contenteditable="true">EditableWithDefaultStyle</span>
</div>

<div>
  <span class = "nowrap" contenteditable="true">EditableWithNoWrapStyle</span>
</div>
```